# Don't understand this proof of equivalence of weak solutions to PDE

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, banach-spaces, hilbert-spaces

I'm trying to understand the proof that (c) implies (a) here in the following proposition (here, $\mathcal{V} = L^2(0,T;V)$). See the very last line in the image for that part:
$$$$

[image]
$$$$
I give here Proposition 1.1 which the proof uses. 
$$$$
[image]

I do not understand how it's used in the proof. I'd appreciate an explanation. Thank you.

---

Here,
$$W_2(0,T) = \{u \in \mathcal V : u' \in \mathcal V'\}$$
and

### [image]

(All images cut from Showalter's book *Monotone Operators in Banach Space*)

Comment: In c) the is no regularity of the time derivative stated. Whereas in a) one has at least in time $u'\in L^2$. Now if you get from c) and i don't see yet why yet, that $A(t)u(t)-f(t)\in \mathcal{V}'$ you get the same for $u'$ due to the equality. Then every term in a) is well defined. However, could you state the assumption on $A(t)$ and $f(t)$?

Comment: @Quickbeam2k1 in a) $u' \in L^2(0,T;V')$. I don't see why $A(t)u(t) - f(t) \in \mathcal{V}'$ in c) implies that $u' \in \mathcal{V}'.$ It only implies that $\frac{d}{dt}(u'(t), \cdot) \in \mathcal{V}'$ by rearranging the equality in c). This is where Prop. 1.1 comes in but I can't see how it's applied.

Comment: Okay $Au-f \in \mathcal{V}'$ means that for any $w\in \mathcal{V}$ with norm $\leq 1$ we find $|(Au-f)w|\leq C |w|$. Now writing it properly down and due to the equality in c we should get the same for $u$. Note that in c) you insert $w=v(x)h(t)$ with $h$ in the right space. Potentially you have to use an density argument i.e. use that you can approximate every $L^2$ function by compactly supported ones.

Comment: @Quickbeam2k1 thanks but I still don't get it..

Comment: What are the assumptions on $A$ and $f$ ?

Comment: $A:\mathcal V \to \mathcal V'$ and $f \in \mathcal V'.$ I understand the first line of your last comment but I don't see how the rest  gives me what I want. You can write an answer with more detail if you like.

Comment: To your point again. Note that in a) it is stated that the weak derivative of $u$ is in $L^2V'$ whereas in c) the weak derivative of $u$ is "only" a distribution

Comment: hey, i read everything again. I think i finally got your problem. Proposition 1.1 only has a meaning if the time derivative is in the same space as the function. What could help is, to use $B=V'$. But then you probably need reflexity of $B$. Can you deduce from c) why $A-fu\in \mathcal{V}$?

Comment: You need [Komura's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C5%8Dmura%27s_theorem), it is near those pages in Showalter if I am not mistaken. In the scope of that result absolute continuity implies strong differentiability almost everywhere and the derivative is Bochner integrable.